# How to write a console application that determines the largest element in a given series of integers

Tags: c#

Write a console application that determines the largest element in a given series of integers.
The numbers are entered one by one, and the application will read them one by one until the user enters the number 0. When the number 0 is entered, the application knows that all the numbers in the string have been entered and displays the largest number.

Number 0 is also a part of the string, and if it is the largest user-entered number then the application will return 0.

Example:

For input:

24
1
-3
3
-1
0
The console will display:

24

and my code is

```
 string[] numbers = new string[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++){
            numbers[i] = "0";
        }

        int biggest = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            if(numbers[i] == "0")
            {
                break;
            }
```

I can't figure out how to continue to resolve this problem. Did I start it in the right way? Please help!

Comment: I have the feeling that you are posting your homework assignments here. While that is fine in and of itself, your questions show a distinct lack of understanding. Don't you have received learning material that you can work through a second time?

Comment: *Sounds* like some homework stuff... So I think you don't get code here, but lets describe the way you chould go. You don't know how many numbers you will get, so use `List<int> numbers = new List<int>()` instead of a string array. You can add elements with `numbers.Add(myNumber)`. You can convert `string` to `int` with `Convert.ToInt32`. Loop until the user enters the breaking char - `"0"` in your case. Iterate the list and find the largest number. Print it. Case closed ;)

Comment: Hints: use `List` instead of array and `while` instead of `for`. Also, `int.Parse` if you are sure only valid numbers are entered or `int.TryParse` if you're not sure.

Comment: I tend to agree with the other comments. Sound a lot like home work. But here are some pointers for a solution. 1) Implement bobble sort of the array. After the sorting is done. the largest integer will be at start of the array or at the end. 2) Iterating all elements in the array storing the largest integer in a result variable. 3) Use Linq, but that kind of eliminate the purpose of learning.

Comment: I hope it's just homework and not a Job interview challenge :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a list of type `List<int>` instead of a string array. Here is my code:

```
List<int> numbers= new List<int>();
int a;
while(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
{
    if (a == 0)
        break;
    else
        numbers.Add(a);
}
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Max());
Console.Read();
```

The first advantage of this approach is that you don't have a user input limit that gives you a string array (in your case only 10 numbers). The second advantage is that you can call the `.Max()` method on a list of the type `List<int>` that gives you the maximum value stored in the list.

In case you want to solve the problem with a string array you can use this code:

```
string[] numbers = new string[10];
int biggest = 0;
int a = 0;
bool isNumber = true;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = Console.ReadLine();

    isNumber = Int32.TryParse(numbers[i], out a);

    if (i == 0)// in case that the first number is negative
    {
        isNumber = Int32.TryParse(numbers[i], out biggest);
    }

    if (numbers[i] == "0" || !isNumber)
    {
       break;
    }
    else
    {
        if (biggest < a)
            biggest = a;
    }
 }
 Console.WriteLine(biggest);
 Console.Read();
```

Comment: This solution works, Yes. But there is no error handling and you use LINQ `Max`. The latter is good for production code, but for learning, implementing methods like those yourself is essential to understand what and how you can do something and how you can solve future problems on your own